# JSON parsing error - No value associated with key CodingKeys

Tags: json, swift, xcode, jsonparser

So, I have tried looking for the answer, I have seen many questions similar to mine. I have tried adding an enum codingKey, I have tried reworking the JSON, but nothing seems to work. I know it's probably something very simple too. (I'm a noob.) Please help.

I am making a Quotes app as part of a project for a course I'm taking.

Here's the code for the Model:

```
import Foundation

class AllQuotes: Identifiable, Decodable {
    
    var id:UUID?
    var quoteTopic:String
    var topicImage:String
    var featured:Bool
    var QuotesList:[Quotes]
}

class Quotes: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id:UUID?
    var name:String
    var actualQuote:String
    var image:String?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case actualQuote = "actualQuote"
        case image = "image"
    }
}
```

Here's my JSON code:

```
[
  {
    "quoteTopic": "Wise Quotes",
    "topicImage": "wise quotes",
    "featured": false,
    "QuotesList": [
      {
        "name": "Lao Tzu",
        "actualQuote": "The journey of a thousand miles begins with one step.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mark Twain",
        "actualQuote": "It is better to keep your mouth closed and let people think you are a fool than to open it and remove all doubt.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mark Twain",
        "actualQuote": "The secret of getting ahead is getting started.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Babe Ruth",
        "actualQuote": "It’s hard to beat a person who never gives up.",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "quoteTopic": "Motivational Quotes",
    "topicImage": "motivational quotes",
    "featured": true,
    "QuotesList": [
      {
        "name": "Mark Twain",
        "actualQuote": "Age is an issue of mind over matter. If you don't mind, it doesn't matter.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mahatma Gandhi",
        "actualQuote": "Learn as if you will live forever, live like you will die tomorrow.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mary Kay Ash",
        "actualQuote": "Don’t limit yourself. Many people limit themselves to what they think they can do. You can go as far as your mind lets you. What you believe, remember, you can achieve.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Unknown",
        "actualQuote": "Hold the vision, trust the process.",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "quoteTopic": "Success Quotes",
    "topicImage": "success quotes",
    "featured": false,
    "QuotesList": [
      {
        "name": "Estee Lauder",
        "actualQuote": "I never dreamed about success. I worked for it.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Thomas Edison",
        "actualQuote": "Opportunity is missed by most people because it is dressed in overalls and looks like work.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Tom Lehrer",
        "actualQuote": "Life is like a sewer… what you get out of it depends on what you put into it.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Walt Disney",
        "actualQuote": "All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them.",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and here's the error I'm getting

Couldn't decode json, try again (to get the actual quote)!
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil) ("name").", underlyingError: nil))

(NOTE: It RUNS/builds fine, but it just won't show the 'QuotesDetailView' page when I try to run it. It's SwiftUI.

Please let me know if I need to provide anymore information, thank you!

**EDIT: here's how I decode my JSON**

```
class DataService {
    
    // Return an array of Quote Objects
    static func getLocalData() -> [AllQuotes] {
        // Begin the process of parsing the JSON File
        
        // Get a URL path to json file
        let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "quotes", ofType: "json")
        
        // Check if pathString is nil, otherwise return empty Quotes List if it is.
        guard pathString != nil else{
            return [AllQuotes]()
        }
        
        // Create URL Object
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString!)
        
        // Create Data Object
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            // Parse the data
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                let quoteData = try decoder.decode([AllQuotes].self, from: data)
                
                // Set unique IDs for each instance
                for newQuote in quoteData {
                    newQuote.id = UUID()
                }
                
                // Return the Quote
                return quoteData
            
            } catch {
                // Couldn't decode json
                print("Couldn't decode json, try again (to get the quotes TOPIC)!")
                print(error)
            }
            
        } catch {
            // Error fetching data from file
            print("There was an error fetching the data from the file. - with the quote list!")
            print(error)
        }
        
        // It didn't work, return an empty Quotes List
        return [AllQuotes]()
    }
    
    // Return an array of ACTUAL Quotes Objects
    static func getActualQuote() -> [Quotes] {
        // Begin the process of parsing the JSON File
        
        // Get a URL path to json file
        let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "quotes", ofType: "json")
        
        // Check if pathString is nil, otherwise return empty Quotes List if it is.
        guard pathString != nil else{
            return [Quotes]()
        }
        
        // Create URL Object
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString!)
        
        // Create Data Object
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            // Parse the data
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                
                let actualQuoteData = try decoder.decode([Quotes].self, from: data)
                
                // Set unique IDs for each instance
                for actualQuote in actualQuoteData {
                    actualQuote.id = UUID()
                }
                
                // Return the Quote
                return actualQuoteData
            
            } catch {
                // Couldn't decode json
                print("Couldn't decode json, try again (to get the actual quote)!")
                print(error)
            }
            
            
        } catch {
            // Error fetching data from file
            print("There was an error fetching the data from the file. - with the actual quote!")
            print(error)
        }
        
        // It didn't work, return an empty Quotes List
        return [Quotes]()
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You have posted two functions, which one are you using?

Comment: I was using both, but my question got answered! I'm about to ask another one though because I have a new issue. Thank you! @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sample code, it shows how to decode your json data, and then display some info:

Since you don't show how you decode your json data, I'm gessing that
the error you get is due to decoding `AllQuotes.self` instead of `[AllQuotes].self` as required.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quoteList = [Quotes]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(quoteList) { quote in
            Text(quote.name)
        }
        .onAppear {
           let json = """
[
  {
    "quoteTopic": "Wise Quotes",
    "topicImage": "wise quotes",
    "featured": false,
    "QuotesList": [
      {
        "name": "Lao Tzu",
        "actualQuote": "The journey of a thousand miles begins with one step.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mark Twain",
        "actualQuote": "It is better to keep your mouth closed and let people think you are a fool than to open it and remove all doubt.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mark Twain",
        "actualQuote": "The secret of getting ahead is getting started.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Babe Ruth",
        "actualQuote": "It’s hard to beat a person who never gives up.",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "quoteTopic": "Motivational Quotes",
    "topicImage": "motivational quotes",
    "featured": true,
    "QuotesList": [
      {
        "name": "Mark Twain",
        "actualQuote": "Age is an issue of mind over matter. If you don't mind, it doesn't matter.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mahatma Gandhi",
        "actualQuote": "Learn as if you will live forever, live like you will die tomorrow.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Mary Kay Ash",
        "actualQuote": "Don’t limit yourself. Many people limit themselves to what they think they can do. You can go as far as your mind lets you. What you believe, remember, you can achieve.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Unknown",
        "actualQuote": "Hold the vision, trust the process.",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "quoteTopic": "Success Quotes",
    "topicImage": "success quotes",
    "featured": false,
    "QuotesList": [
      {
        "name": "Estee Lauder",
        "actualQuote": "I never dreamed about success. I worked for it.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Thomas Edison",
        "actualQuote": "Opportunity is missed by most people because it is dressed in overalls and looks like work.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Tom Lehrer",
        "actualQuote": "Life is like a sewer… what you get out of it depends on what you put into it.",
        "image": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Walt Disney",
        "actualQuote": "All our dreams can come true, if we have the courage to pursue them.",
        "image": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
"""
                if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
                    do {
                        let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([AllQuotes].self, from: data)
                        // print something
                        for quote in apiResponse {
                            print("---> quoteTopic: \(quote.quoteTopic)")
                            // all quotes
                            quoteList.append(contentsOf: quote.QuotesList)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("decode error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                 
            }
    }
    
}

class AllQuotes: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()  // <-- here
    var quoteTopic:String
    var topicImage:String
    var featured:Bool
    var QuotesList:[Quotes]
    
    // -- here
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        // <-- here remove id
        case quoteTopic, topicImage, featured, QuotesList
    }
}

class Quotes: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID() // <-- here
    var name:String
    var actualQuote:String
    var image:String?
    
    // -- here
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        // <-- here remove id
        case name = "name"
        case actualQuote = "actualQuote"
        case image = "image"
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: in view of the "new" code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var quoteList = [Quotes]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(quoteList) { quote in
            Text(quote.name)
        }
        .onAppear {
            quoteList = DataService.getActualQuote()
            print("---> quoteList: \(quoteList)")
        }
    }
}

class DataService {
    
    // Return an array of Quote Objects
    static func getLocalData() -> [AllQuotes] {
        // Begin the process of parsing the JSON File
        
        // Get a URL path to json file
        let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "quotes", ofType: "json")
        
        // Check if pathString is nil, otherwise return empty Quotes List if it is.
        guard pathString != nil else{
            return [AllQuotes]()
        }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString!)
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            do {
                let quoteData = try JSONDecoder().decode([AllQuotes].self, from: data)
                return quoteData
            } catch {
                // Couldn't decode json
                print("Couldn't decode json, try again (to get the quotes TOPIC)!")
                print(error)
            }
        } catch {
            // Error fetching data from file
            print("There was an error fetching the data from the file. - with the quote list!")
            print(error)
        }
        
        // It didn't work, return an empty Quotes List
        return []
    }
    
    // Return an array of ACTUAL Quotes Objects
    static func getActualQuote() -> [Quotes] {
        // Begin the process of parsing the JSON File
        
        // Get a URL path to json file
        let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "quotes", ofType: "json")
        
        // Check if pathString is nil, otherwise return empty Quotes List if it is.
        guard pathString != nil else{
            return [Quotes]()
        }
        
        // Create URL Object
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString!)
        
        // Create Data Object
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            do {
                // -- here
                let quoteData = try JSONDecoder().decode([AllQuotes].self, from: data)
                // -- here
                var actualQuoteData = [Quotes]()
                for quote in quoteData {
                    actualQuoteData.append(contentsOf: quote.QuotesList)
                }
                // Return the Quotes
                return actualQuoteData
            } catch {
                // Couldn't decode json
                print("Couldn't decode json, try again (to get the actual quote)!")
                print(error)
            }
        } catch {
            // Error fetching data from file
            print("There was an error fetching the data from the file. - with the actual quote!")
            print(error)
        }
        
        // It didn't work, return an empty Quotes List
        return []
    }

}
```

EDIT-2: you can shorten your code, such as:

```
class DataService {
    
    // Return an array of Quote Objects
    static func getLocalData() -> [AllQuotes] {
        if let pathString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "quotes", ofType: "json") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString)
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let quoteData = try JSONDecoder().decode([AllQuotes].self, from: data)
                return quoteData
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return []
    }
    
    // Return an array of ACTUAL Quotes Objects
    static func getActualQuote() -> [Quotes] {
        var actualQuoteData = [Quotes]()
        for quote in getLocalData() {
            actualQuoteData.append(contentsOf: quote.QuotesList)
        }
        return actualQuoteData
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added how I decoded my JSON, if that will help!

Comment: does my code work for you?

Comment: I think so...here's what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/D7fdVP9

Comment: I got SOMETHING to show up with your code, which is better than what I've been trying and failing to get lol.

Comment: is something wrong with how I'm decoding my JSON?

Comment: yes there is, here: `let actualQuoteData = try decoder.decode([Quotes].self, from: data)`. You json data is `[AllQuotes]`, not `[Quotes]`. See my updated answer (EDIT-1).

Comment: gotchya, perfect, I understand now, thank you!